# Simple query freezes with PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, freeze

We used PL/SQL Developer 7, Devart ODAC 6 on Delphi 7, while connecting to Oracle 8 and it worked fine. Recently we upgraded to Oracle 10g R2 and a simple query `select from table that contain 10 Column and 200 Rows` on PL/SQL developer and ODAC works on LAN but freezes over the internet.

I tried 3 Tiers application (Database Server and Application Server in Same LAN, client over the Netwrok), it worked fine also.  I have a lot of the appliation written in Delphi/ODAC/Fastreport.

Do you know what would cause it to freeze?

Comment: So, if you run the query directly from sqlplus, what happens?

Comment: Do you have any intrusion detection running between the Internet and your LAN? Sounds like maybe something is tripping and dropping the data packets. Assuming youz're able to connect to the DB at all, of course.

Comment: SQL*Plus work Fine...,even we select a huge of data, but pl/sql Developer Freeze , TOAD crash, ODAC/delphi Freeze, PL/SQL Developer 8,9 and 10 crash

Comment: we work on intranet but in different location ,  not internet